# How to stop a React render on media queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, media-queries

I have existing CSS (therefore, I should consider it) that includes media queries whether to display an element. The CSS works as expected but the problem is that React still re-renders and re-structures the DOM even when the media query causes the element not to be re-rendered anyway.

Is there any way to tell react not to render? Is there a way to detect the media query in React and then not render if the media query says not to?

Comment: Media queries don't affect the DOM. Media queries have no effect on whether React should render or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) and return `false` from `shouldComponentUpdate`

Something like the following depending on your use-case

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches
}
```